# Can this java snippet be re-written?

Tags: java

Can anyone suggest how to re-write the following Java snippet and if so why it would be inappropriate, thanks !!

```
try {
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
        a[i++].func();
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
}
```

Comment: Ist this homework?

Comment: Do you understand what is that doing? If so, you have to know why it is inappropriate...

Comment: This is covered in Item 42 of [*Java Puzzlers*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Puzzlers-Traps-Pitfalls-Corner/dp/032133678X/).

Answer (score 8):

Use a [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop:

```
for(TypeOfArray item : a) {
    item.func();
}
```

Or alternatively a simple for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].func();
}
```

The resulting bytecode is more or less the same but I find for-each loops more elegant. Your code is inappropriate, because it:

- uses Exceptions for flow control
- uses a while(true) loop (simply don't use it if there is any other way)

Answer (score 4):

As a good general principle, you should not use exceptions for flow control. And frankly, running off the end of an array is just being slack.

Try using a "foreach" loop:

```
for (IHasFunc hasFunc : a) {
    hasFunc.func();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an exception to end the loop. Use `a.length` to determine the size.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `for` loop thus:

```
for (YourObject obj : a) {
   obj.func();
}
```

then you avoid the requirement for an indexing variable.

As noted, exceptions aren't good for flow control. They're expensive to create and tracing their execution flow is difficult.